# Convert from Quaternary to Hexadecimal

Tags: number-systems

I have the number (23011) in Quaternary and I have to convert it to Hexadecimal. Tried looking up for help online, but other convertors who convert the number without any explanations how it's done manually... any help is appreciated.. thank you.

Comment: This article explains what quaternary (base four) notation means: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternary_numeral_system  (Note: Your tag, "quaternions," means something very different in math.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: 2 digits in base 4 (Quaternary) can represent a digit in Hex. 
eg, $33_4 = F_{16}$

Answer (score 0):

Base 4 just uses 2 digits for every 0-15 represented by a Hex number.
Just pair from rightmost number and translate.